# How to adjust too small chart size in QChartview (GUI designed in through QTDesigner)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qchart, qchartview

I have designed a GUI in QTDesigner where I want to include a Doughnut chart using PyQT5's QChart. I have achieved to get the Chart itself visible and hide the legend. However, I have no clue how to make the chart fit the full area of the defined Chartview area. It stays really small as shown in the picture.

[image]

Here are the relevant snippets of my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,  QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QPieSeries
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
import csv
from operator import itemgetter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1118, 702)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 1091, 611))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
    
    # removed a lot of other graphical elements for readability
        
        self.t_type_pressure = QtWidgets.QWidget()              #create a tab which contains a group box
        self.t_type_pressure.setObjectName("t_type_pressure")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.t_type_pressure)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 511, 311))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gv_all_types = QChartView(self.groupBox)           #add a QChartView to the group box
        self.gv_all_types.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 20, 100, 150)) #set the size of the QChartView container which holds the chart
        self.gv_all_types.setObjectName("gv_all_types")
        

        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        # removed the connections between buttons and functions, one of them called the connectCSVDatabase

    
    def connectCSVDatabase(self):
        # do connection to database here and get data

        # ... get data from CSV file

        # initialize all data containers in GUI
        self.series_all_types = QPieSeries()
        self.series_all_types.setHoleSize(0.45)
        self.series_all_types.setPieSize(1)
        self.series_all_types.append('A', 1).setColor(QColor(0,148,255))
        self.series_all_types.append('B', 1).setColor(QColor(255,144,0))
        self.series_all_types.append('C', 1).setColor(QColor(255,8,0))
        self.series_all_types.hide()


        self.chart_all_types = self.gv_all_types.chart()
        self.chart_all_types.addSeries(self.series_all_types)
        self.chart_all_types.setBackgroundRoundness(0)
        self.chart_all_types.layout().setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
        
        self.update_shown_data()

    def update_shown_data(self):
        # clear the existing series and add the new ones
        self.series_all_types.clear()
        self.series_all_types.append('A', 10).setColor(QColor(0,148,255))
        self.series_all_types.append('B', 20).setColor(QColor(255,144,0))
        self.series_all_types.append('C', 30).setColor(QColor(255,8,0))

        self.chart_all_types.addSeries(self.series_all_types)
```

With the above code my container is clearly visible in the GUI, but the chart itself is really small (see included picture). I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: You need to use layout managers. See [layout managers in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Also, don't edit files generated by pyuic, but import them just as they are generated. See [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)

Comment: Dear @musicamante, thank you for your response. I did use the layout manager, but for some reason I cannot control the layout of the chart I place in my GraphicsView promoted to QChartView. Right-clicking on the promoted GraphicsView widget I can select only layout -> adjust size, which makes it bigger. To me it feels as if there is space reserved above the chart for a title and legend, which is not released even though they are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this after adding the following line to the code after creating the chart:

```
self.chart_all_alarms.setPlotArea(QtCore.QRectF(0,0,100,130))
```

I found the following in the Qt documentation: [The plot area does not include the area defined by margins. By default this will resize if inside a QChartView. If an explicit size is set for the plot area then it will respect this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#plotArea-prop)